# One switch, two lights, add a third always-on

Tags: switch, light, fans

I have an existing light switch (single-pole) that turns on two LED lights on the front porch. I’m considering converting the last light in the series to a ceiling fan and adding an additional porch light in between the first light and the new fan. I would like to have the first two lights controlled by the light switch (on/off) and the fan at the end of the series always-on (it will be controlled by a remote control sold with the fan). That way I can have the fan on during the hot day without running the patio lights. Is that even possible?

Comment: how would the fan maintain power when the light switch is turned off?

Comment: It all depends on how easy it will be to run new wiring between the switch box and the two lights. It is very unlikely that you already have enough wires in place to do this.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the existing boxes please?

Comment: Everything is possible if you make enough effort. You need to run wires in addition to existing.

Comment: Just about anything is possible, dusk to dawn sensors on the outside lights so they are not on in the day time as 1 simple way to do it or add a new circuit.

Answer (score 1):

### Careful selection of smart switches and lights

You physically wire the whole shebang to deliver always-hot and neutral to all points. (including the switch).

Then you fit smart fixtures (or smart bulbs in dumb fixtures), and fit a compatible smart switch, and then do the magic bit that makes the bulbs obey the switch.

Such product selection is outside the scope of what we do on StackExchange, but there are plenty of products not specifically made to solve this problem, but able to do it as a side-effect.